# interval regular expression in awk doesnt work as expected

Tags: regex, awk

I have a bunch of files that have comma separated fields and I'm on redhat linux. I'm executing the following awk command like this:

```
 awk  --re-interval -F "," '$4~/xyz:8080\/proxyval\/getPages.do\?fd=1d[0-9]{1}/ { print }' *

204:1,204,null,xyz:8080/proxyval/getPages.do?fd=1d7d7 ----> dont expect to see this 
204:1,204,null,xyz:8080/proxyval/getPages.do?fd=1d8
204:1,204,null,xyz:8080/proxyval/getPages.do?fd=1d8d8  ----> dont expect to see this   
204:1,204,null,xyz:8080/proxyval/getPages.do?fd=1d3
```

The `fd=1d[0-9]{1}` part of regxp  should match only `fd=1d8` `fd=1d3` but it seems to match  `fd=1d7d7` and 'fd=1d8d8' also. Please let me know If I'm missing something here.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: If you need the `--re-interval` flag to enable RE intervals then you are using an extremely old version of gawk, get a new one. Also, `{print}` is the default action given a true condition, you don't need to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Regexp matches find substrings, not whole strings; to find an exact match, you must anchor the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of string. `[0-9]{1}` is equivalent to `[0-9]` (one character from `0` to `9`).

I.e. `fd=1d[0-9]{1}` will find `blahfd=1d8732`, with the matched region being `fd=1d8`; `^fd=1d[0-9]$` will not match it, but will match `fd=1d8`.